# Strongswan Packets are not routed

Tags: vpn, routing, strongswan

I'm trying to configure strongswan as a IKEv2 VPN server behind my NAT.
The network topology looks the following:

The VPN server (10.0.0.1) is behind a NAT (Default Gateway 10.0.0.138) which forwards UDP Port 4500 and Port 500 to the VPN server.
The VPN server runs Fedora 28 with SELinux set to permissive.

I installed StrongSwan with the DHCP and FARP plugins enabled.
My road warriors are able to connect to my VPN server, authenticate against it and even obtain an IP address (I'm trying it from my iPhone).

For some reason, I can't reach any local network devices from my work warrior. Also, when I try to ping the iPhone from my local laptop, I can see on the VPN server via tcpdump that an ARP request is sent but I can also see in Wireshark on my laptop that no response is ever sent. So my guess is that the FARP plugin is not properly working.

I enabled ip forwarding on the VPN server.
Are any further steps required to activate and get FARP working? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Btw. here is my IPSec.conf file:

```
config setup
    charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
    uniqueids=no
conn ikev2-vpn
    auto=add
    compress=no
    # type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ikev2
    fragmentation=yes
    forceencaps=yes
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftid=@server.somename.com
    leftcert=server-cert.pem
    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/24
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightsourceip=%dhcp
    rightsubnet=10.0.0.0/24
    rightdns=10.0.0.1,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
    rightsendcert=never
    eap_identity=%identity
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sha256,aes256-sha1,3des-sha1!
    # Dead peer detection. For MOBIKE, let high delay
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    leftfirewall=yes
```

And here is the output of `ipsec statusall`

```
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.6.3, Linux 4.17.14-202.fc28.x86_64, x86_64):
  uptime: 25 minutes, since Aug 29 10:24:12 2018
  malloc: sbrk 2695168, mmap 0, used 835536, free 1859632
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 4
  loaded plugins: charon pkcs11 aes des rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl gcrypt fips-prf gmp curve25519 agent xcbc cmac hmac attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default farp stroke vici updown eap-identity eap-md5 eap-mschapv2 eap-tls eap-ttls xauth-generic dhcp addrblock counters
Listening IP addresses:
  10.0.0.1
  172.18.0.1
  172.17.0.1
Connections:
   ikev2-vpn:  %any...%any  IKEv2, dpddelay=300s
   ikev2-vpn:   local:  [server.somename.com] uses public key authentication
   ikev2-vpn:    cert:  "CN=server.somename.com"
   ikev2-vpn:   remote: uses EAP_MSCHAPV2 authentication with EAP identity '%any'
   ikev2-vpn:   child:  0.0.0.0/24 === 10.0.0.0/24 TUNNEL, dpdaction=clear
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
   ikev2-vpn[4]: ESTABLISHED 12 seconds ago, 10.0.0.1[server.somename.com]...213.147.166.1[user]
   ikev2-vpn[4]: IKEv2 SPIs: 3cdf025026a86a29_i a2f389a38a5326d4_r*, rekeying disabled
   ikev2-vpn[4]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_1024
   ikev2-vpn{4}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 2, ESP in UDP SPIs: cdb9b943_i 083b3ef7_o
   ikev2-vpn{4}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128, 0 bytes_i, 0 bytes_o, rekeying disabled
   ikev2-vpn{4}:   0.0.0.0/24 === 10.0.0.0/24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *left|rightsubnet* configuration is incorrect.

You want to use `leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0` to tunnel everything, with `/24` only traffic to *0.0.0.0-0.0.0.255* would get tunneled (note, though, that iOS will never send traffic to the server's public IP and the subnet it itself is connected to via VPN).

And when using [virtual IPs](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/VirtualIp) (*rightsourceip* set) you don't want to set *rightsubnet* as the client's address is dynamically assigned. So just remove that setting or set it to *%dynamic*.